# Голосование для большого количества участников

Tags: php, mysql, массивы, yii2

Здравствуйте. Помогите пожалуйста решить такую проблему. Проект на Yii2. Есть, допустим, чемпионат (видеобатлы), принять участие могут от 2 до 64 человек. Создается чемпионат, пользователи подают заявки и добавляют свои видео. Все это записывается в бд,
таблица с батлами `c_competition`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
таблица с заявками `c_requests`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
таблица с вариантами `c_option`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
это все готово.
Проблема заключается в том, что я не могу придумать как всех участников рандомно разбить по парам, таким образом что бы потом запоминать результаты ( кто победил, а кто проиграл). И потом из победителей сформировать еще пары и так далее, пока не останется только один - победитель.
Страница голосования сейчас выглядит вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
но варианты выводятся всей кучей, если проголосовать за одного, то больше ни за кого нельзя будет, а мне нужно что бы пары были независимы, что бы можно было проголосовать за человека в каждой паре.
Я думал сделать так: написать функцию, которая будет брать варианты, группировать их по 2 и записывать в еще одну таблицу, но что-то не получается у меня сообразить, как это организовать. Может кто-нибудь делал нечто подобное, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: У вас достаточно репутации для того, чтобы самостоятельно в вопрос вставить фото, а не ссылки на них. Сделайте это и всегда, если нужно, делайте

Comment: Ну вам надо заиметь какую-то сущность типа `Versus` у которой будет `user1`, `user2`, `ratingUser1`, `ratingUser2`, `winner` и еще одну сущность типа `VersusManager` который бы в начале имел стек из сущностей `Versus` (предварительно сформированных) и когда все раунды 1 этапа прошли он бы формировал новый стек из `Versus` победителей. Соответственно для каждой сущности Versus нужно иметь запись в таблице (например `c_battle` или `c_versus` )

Comment: @Rochfort Спасибо. Вот вашим способом получается, оформите как ответ, если желаете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вам надо заиметь какую-то сущность типа `Versus` у которой будет `user1`, `user2`, `ratingUser1`, `ratingUser2`, `winner` и еще одну сущность типа `VersusManager` который бы в начале имел стек из сущностей `Versus` (предварительно сформированных) и когда все раунды 1 этапа прошли он бы формировал новый стек из `Versus` победителей. Соответственно для каждой сущности Versus нужно иметь запись в таблице (например `c_battle` или `c_versus` )

Answer (score 0):

Нужна одна общая база данных с полями данных `next_tour` (номер ближайшего тура) и `next_tour_id`(`id` участника в ближайшем туре).
Вначале `next_tour_id` формировать рандомно.
Участник без пары и победители сражений получают следующий номер по каждому из этих полей.
Участников следующего тура фильтровать по `next_tour`, а пары составлять из участников с ближайшими `next_tour_id`.